# How to run Python3 virtual environment on CENTOS 7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, centos7, virtual-environment

I have a machine with Centos 7 installed. By default Centos 7 comes with python 2.7 installed. I have added python 3 but I didn't not change the PATH as I don't want to mess with the default python version used by the operating system.

Now I want to create a project using python 3 and the latest version of django so I have created a virtual environment using the command:

```
python3 -m venv python3-RIGS-venv
```

if I try to activate it using:

```
source python3-RIGS-venv/bin/activate
```

I get the following error:

```
Badly placed ()'s.
```

I assume because the default python is 2.7 and not 3 that I have used to create the venv. I have also tried:

```
python3 python3-RIGS-venv/bin/activate
```

with the following result:

```
File "python3-RIGS-venv/bin/activate", line 4
deactivate () {
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

and finally:

```
cd python3-RIGS-venv/bin/
. activate
```

that gives the following error:

```
./activate: Permission denied.
```

So the question is how do I activate a venv created with python3 but on a machine running python 2 as default?

Comment: What shell are you running?

Comment: Hi mx0, I am using csh

Comment: Thank you mx0 for your question. I had a look the bin folder and found the activate.csh so I have run
source activate.csh and it worked!
If you turn your question into an answer I will vote it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `venv/bin/` catalog are scripts for activating a virtual environment for different shells. For csh use `activate.csh`.